# Webscraping with powerquery

Tags: excel, powerquery

I'm trying to get data from a website in Excel 2016 using Powerquery but I cannot get it to work. The server returns an error page. I do get the page I want in Chrome and in Postman (Chrome app) when I pass in the same cookie to the same asp page.

Code:

```
    let
    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents("http://portal.icuregswe.org/utdata/_render.aspx", [Headers=[Cookie="__utmt=1; ASP.NET_SessionId=wr4drsm5nqctyk55qcecgiap; __utma=223509914.878319927.1493184252.1493492055.1493534562.4; __utmb=223509914.3.10.1493534562; __utmc=223509914; __utmz=223509914.1493534562.4.4.utmcsr=icuregswe.org|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/sv/Utdata/Utdataportal-Ny/; __utma=187689776.292092926.1493485249.1493492045.1493534550.3; __utmb=187689776.3.10.1493534550; __utmc=187689776; __utmz=187689776.1493485249.1.1.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); ASP.NET_SessionId=wr4drsm5nqctyk55qcecgiap; __utma=223509914.878319927.1493184252.1493492055.1493534562.4; __utmb=223509914.3.10.1493534562; __utmc=223509914; __utmz=223509914.1493534562.4.4.utmcsr=icuregswe.org|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/sv/Utdata/Utdataportal-Ny/"]])),
    Data0 = Source{0}[Data]
in
    Data0
```

DOM structure:

[image: DOM structure]

Error message:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
at _render.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) 
at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) 
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() 
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Suspect that the server is missing some input to generate the page(using dev tools in Chrome one can see that there are several calls to the server and I'm not sure how it works in that respect).

The main page is here:
http://portal.icuregswe.org/utdata/

Reports are accessed via the menu, e.g.: Rapporter->Produktion->Vårdtid->Vårddygn summa

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: I previously thought I had figured it out but once I tried to scrape a different report on the same site I realized that it didn't work. I came up with this solution that involves a VB-script and Power Query:

To use one needs to get a cookie value with a session id from the site by choosing "Urval", selecting a time period and selecting a report. This will return a cookie with a session id, copy this value into cell B4(which has to be named cookievalue). Once this is set one clicks an update button which executes the VB script below. This will call the website to set the report type for the current session id and then update the Power Query which will fetch a CSV from the site.

The sheet is named parameters.

[Excel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgJbD.png)

Power Query to fetch CSV from site:

```
let
    cookiestr = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="cookievalue"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
    Source = Excel.Workbook(Web.Contents("http://portal.icuregswe.org/utdata/ExcelExport.aspx", [Headers=[Cookie=cookiestr]]), null, true),
    #"SIR-rapport_Sheet" = Source{[Item="SIR-rapport",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data]
in
    #"SIR-rapport_Sheet"
```

VB script to call website and set report type and update Power Query:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim URL As String
URL = Sheets("parameters").Range("B2")
Dim param As String
param = Sheets("parameters").Range("B3")
Dim cookie As String
cookie = Sheets("parameters").Range("B4")

Dim w As New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
w.Open "POST", URL & param, False
w.setRequestHeader "Cookie", cookie
w.send qs

'Macro to update Power Query script(s)
Dim lTest As Long, cn As WorkbookConnection
On Error Resume Next
For Each cn In ThisWorkbook.Connections
lTest = InStr(1, cn.OLEDBConnection.Connection, "Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1", vbTextCompare)
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
Err.Clear
Exit For
End If
If lTest > 0 Then cn.Refresh
Next cn
End Sub
```

Sources:

- [Set/Get Web Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345485/set-get-web-cookies)
- http://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2014/10/22/refresh-power-query-with-vba/